# javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Fault code QName must be namespace qualified! when deploying in weblogic server 12c

Tags: java, web-services, soap, weblogic

When I am deploying a struts2 project from tomcat to weblogic server 12c, I am getting below exception when i am connecting to an esb thru soapHandler stub.

The soapHandler is getting proper fault envelope from esb.But after that it is showing below Exception:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Fault code QName '2104' must be namespace qualified!
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:195)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:128)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:253)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:205)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:292)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:92)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:161)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:453)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:292)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:255)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:510)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3654)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3620)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:196)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2423)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2258)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1626)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1586)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
Caused By: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Fault code QName '2104' must be namespace qualified!
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.soap.soap11.Fault11.setFaultCode(Fault11.java:334)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.soap.soap11.SOAPFactory11.createFault(SOAPFactory11.java:51)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.soap.SOAPFactoryImpl.createFault(SOAPFactoryImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:184)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:128)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:253)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:205)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:292)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:92)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:161)
```

The fault message I am getting from esb is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" S:mustUnderstand="1">
         <wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Timestamp-2433">
            <wsu:Created>2016-08-29T12:20:48.317Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2016-08-29T12:25:48.317Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
      </wsse:Security>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <S:Body>
      <S:Fault xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
         <faultcode>2104</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Device Id is required</faultstring>
      </S:Fault>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

The real issue was

previously I was using com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap but when I am using weblogic it is using (its own jar ) oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.soap.soap11.

I have tried below methods to solve But Couldnt able to

1. inside weblogic.xml I have provided below lines

   ```
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
       <wls:package-name>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.*</wls:package-name>
       <wls:package-name>com.sun.xml.ws.api.wsdl.parser.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>javax.xml.ws.soap.*</wls:package-name>
       </wls:prefer-application-packages>
       <wls:prefer-application-resources>
       <wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.xml.ws.*    </wls:resource-name> 
   <wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/com.sun.xml.ws.*</wls:resource-name> 
   <wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/com.sun.tools.ws.*    </wls:resource-name>
       </wls:prefer-application-resources>
   </wls:container-descriptor>
   ```

2.loged to admin console of weblogic . "Servers > Managed Server Name (link) > Server Start (tab) > Arguments: (box)"
I have given

```
   JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djavax.xml.soap.MessageFactory=com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl"
```

3.In the startWeblogic.sh file I have given

```
if "%WLS_REDIRECT_LOG%"=="" (
    echo Starting WLS with line:
    echo %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java %JAVA_VM% %MEM_ARGS% -Dweblogic.Name=%SERVER_NAME% -Djava.security.policy=%WLS_POLICY_FILE% %JAVA_OPTIONS% %PROXY_SETTINGS% %SERVER_CLASS%
    %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java %JAVA_VM% %MEM_ARGS% -Djavax.xml.soap.MessageFactory=com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl -Dweblogic.Name=%SERVER_NAME% -Djava.security.policy=%WLS_POLICY_FILE% %JAVA_OPTIONS% %PROXY_SETTINGS% %SERVER_CLASS%
) else (
    echo Redirecting output from WLS window to %WLS_REDIRECT_LOG%
    %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java %JAVA_VM% %MEM_ARGS% -Dweblogic.Name=%SERVER_NAME% -Djavax.xml.soap.MessageFactory=com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl -Djava.security.policy=%WLS_POLICY_FILE% %JAVA_OPTIONS% %PROXY_SETTINGS% %SERVER_CLASS%  >"%WLS_REDIRECT_LOG%" 2>&1 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue got resolved by following way.

I took the saaj-impl-1.3.10.jar from my war file and copied into weblogic %DOMAIN_HOME%\lib\ folder then added  below lines into setDomainEnv.cmd file of weblogic

set PRE_CLASSPATH=%DOMAIN_HOME%\lib\saaj-impl-1.3.10.jar

then restarted the weblogic server.Issue got resolved

Answer (score 0):

The correct prefered package is

```
<wls:package-name>javax.xml.soap.*</wls:package-name>
```

You don't need to change the classpath of weblogic. But saaj-impl (and its dependencies) should be in your war file, weblogic does not pick up the one that comes with the JDK.

Maven config to add saaj dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
  <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

My resolution for this issue for Weblogic 12.1.3:

1. Copy `saaj-impl-1.3.25.jar` to weblogic server directory `${DOMAIN_HOME}/lib`
2. To element `<container-descriptor>` of `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/weblogic.xml` is needed add preferred application resource:

   ```
   <prefer-application-resources>
     <resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.xml.soap.*</resource-name>
   </prefer-application-resources>
   ```
3. Restart server, rebuild and redeploy application.